# How to speed up the training in neural network when mini-batch training is used?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Can anyone give me some ideas on possible techniques to speed up the training process of multilayer artificial neural network if the training involves mini-batch?

So far, I understand that stochastic training probably leads to a faster convergence but, if we have to use mini-batch training, is there any way to make the convergence faster?

(Some pointers to relevant papers will also help!)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of general tips, you may want to be using a GPU when writing your neural network; they lead to huge improvements in speed and performance. See http://web.stanford.edu/~acoates/papers/CoatesHuvalWangWuNgCatanzaro_icml2013.pdf

In terms of machine learning, better weight initialization leads to faster convergence. One method of doing this is unsupervised feature learning. See http://web.stanford.edu/~acoates/papers/CoatesLeeNg_nips2010_dlwkshp_singlelayer.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot for these useful links. I am currently focusing on distributed systems and have recently found that adaptive learning rate and momentum help speeding up my training too. Also found that the course called "Neural Networks for Machine Learning" in coursera is full of useful information about this stuff.